# Pattern checking.check of incorrect number of operators and brackets

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In an expression , How to

1. 1.Check if operators and operands are correct or not.
2. 2.check if brackets match or not.

**Example 1**: `(a+b)-` has a one extra operator How do i confirm that the number of operators are incorrect.

**Example 2** :`((a+b)/(c-d)` has one extra opening bracket. how to check such irregularities. 
Any regular expression pattern to check these or some way to do this ?

Comment: If the formula structure is similar, you can use regular expression. Or else you have to use Stack to solve for irregularities.

Comment: The number of operators here shouldnt be more or less. (a+b) should have one oopertor only.

Comment: Thats just 1 sample of input. If it keeps varying in different formats, then no regular xpression can help you. You gotta write your own logic for that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a simple answer.. I was just a math minor in college.  My suggestion would be to use a 3rd party dll for this task.

1) [Mathdotnet](http://www.mathdotnet.com/), A mathematical open source (MIT/X11, LGPL & GPL) library written in C#/.Net, aiming to provide a self contained clean framework for symbolic algebraic and numerical / scientific computations.

2) [IMSL™ C# Numerical Library for Microsoft® .NET Applications](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=6376605) (Paid)

3) [Extreme Optimization Mathematics Library for .NET](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/mathematics/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to write a very simple parser. You could check out [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/).